# Concatenate Numpy arrays of different shape

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to create a numpy array by concatenating two or more numpy arrays with shape (1, x, 1) where x is variable.

Here is the problem in detail.

```
x1 = #numpy array with shape (x,)
x2 = #numpy array with shape (y,)

#create batch
x1 = np.expand_dims(x1, 0) #shape (1, x)
x2 = np.expand_dims(x2, 0) #shape (1, y)

#add channel dimension
x1 = np.expand_dims(x1, -1) #shape (1, x, 1)
x2 = np.expand_dims(x2, -1) #shape (1, y, 1)

#merge the two arrays
x = np.concatenate((x1, x2), axis=0)
#expected shape (2, ??, 1)
```

Note the expected shape (2, ??, 1). I am wondering if what I am trying to do is doable.

Executing this code raises a ValueError:

> ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 138241 and the array at index 1 has size 104321

Comment: So you start with shapes (x,) and (y,), expand them to (1,x,1) and (1,y,1).  And try concatenate on the initial 1's.  It's complaining the `x` is not the same as `y`.  You can only make a (2,n,1) if `x` is the same as `y`.

Comment: What do you expect to get? What values do you expect `??` to be, given x and y?